# Firebug debugging parsing error?

Tags: firebug

I am getting some wierdness with the Firebug debugger.  I have screenshots that explain the problem:

http://www.tqis.com/pen/eloquency/images/tmp/before.png

As this screenshot demonstrates, the line numbers after 885 are not colored green, which means Firebug does not recognize these statements as executable code.

After a confounding hour or so, I got these results

http://www.tqis.com/pen/eloquency/images/tmp/after.png

The only difference between the files in the editor is the commented blank line.

This seems like an unreliable workaround.  Can anyone share something more helpful?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are Firebug bugs related to this:

- [Issue 4646](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=4646): Incorrect marking of lines as executable
- [Issue 5081](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=5081): Does not stop on breakpoints

Also note that somebody else [asked because of a very similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16478914/firebug-debug-problems-with-switch-statement) lately.

The Firebug Working Group is currently working on [moving to a new debugger API](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=5421), which should (hopefully) fix such problems.