# Firebug debug problems with switch statement

Tags: firebug

When I have a switch statement in JavaScript and I want to debug this in Firebug,
I cannot place a break point to the lines of one case, because the line numbers there
are greyed out (the rest is green)!

For example: Line 1347 or 1350

Firefox version: 20.0
Firebug version: 1.11.2

[image]

Thanks alot in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2):

This is probably the same bug as [issue 6441](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=6441).

You should set the breakpoint at the `case` statement, i.e. line 1346 and then step through your code.

Note that such questions about Firebug should better be asked inside the [Firebug discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/firebug). Otherwise the Firebug Working Group may not get to know about it.

Also there was [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16468679/firebug-debugging-parsing-error) one day before yours.

Comment: Hello Sebastian. Thank you for pointing me to this similar question.